# Is it possible to watch Assassin's Creed Revelation's last cutscene without restarting a new game? (Spoiler)

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I've completed AC Revelations. I want to watch Revelation's last cutscene,

> where it is seen that the Earth is nearly destroyed.

It is possible to replay any mission from DNA menu. I played the very last mission but the game takes me back to DNA menu before starting the cutscene.

Is it possible to watch it again from the game without completing it another time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In-game, no, there doesn't appear to be any way to replay cutscenes or videos that aren't part of the memory. In this case, your best bet may be to watch it on YouTube.